# EditTexts aren't working when orientation changes?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-orientation

I am needing to reformat an existing Android app to have a landscape version. It uses a TextWatcher to calculate a tip amount when numbers are entered into 2 EditTexts (bill amount & tip percent). It works by itself, but when I add a second layout, the TextWatcher stops working and doesn't calculate anything. It rotates and looks how I want it to, but doesn't function. My landscape layout has all the same parts as the portrait with the same EditText & TextView IDs. This is what I am using to change the layouts:

```
package com.example.tiporientation;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TipCalculator tipCalc;
    private NumberFormat money = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    private EditText billEditText;
    private EditText tipEditText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        tipCalc = new TipCalculator(.17f,100);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        billEditText = findViewById(R.id.EDIT_BillAmount);
        tipEditText = findViewById(R.id.EDIT_EnterTip);

        //create inner-class for this... puts it at bottom of MainActivity
        //TextChangeHandler is a "listener"
        //attach it to our EDIT texts, so it is listening to changes in bill $ & tip %
        TextChangeHandler tch = new TextChangeHandler();
        billEditText.addTextChangedListener(tch);
        tipEditText.addTextChangedListener(tch);
        Configuration config = getResources().getConfiguration();
        modifyLayout(config);
    }

    private void modifyLayout(Configuration newConfig) {
        if(newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_landscape); //we create new XML for this layout
        else if(newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        Log.w("MainActivity", "Inside onConfigurationChanged");
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        modifyLayout(newConfig); //if orientation changes again, send back to modifyLayout
    }

    public void calculate () {
        //convert edit texts to a string ???
        String billString = billEditText.getText().toString();
        String tipString = tipEditText.getText().toString();

        //2 text views from XML
        TextView tipTextView = findViewById(R.id.TXT_TipTotal);
        TextView totalTextView = findViewById(R.id.TXT_TotalAmount);

        try {
            //convert billString to float & tipString to int -- can't do math with strings
            float billAmount = Float.parseFloat(billString);
            int tipPercent = Integer.parseInt(tipString);
            //update the model -- referencing TipCalculator class!
            tipCalc.setBill(billAmount);
            tipCalc.setTip(.01f * tipPercent);
            //ask model to calculate
            float tip = tipCalc.tipAmount();
            float total = tipCalc.totalAmount();
            //update view with formatted tip & total amount
            tipTextView.setText(money.format(tip));
            totalTextView.setText(money.format(total));
        } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) { }
    }

    //create implements... select all 3 they are then stubbed out in the class
    private class TextChangeHandler implements TextWatcher {
        @Override
             public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }
        @Override
             public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }
        @Override
             public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
             calculate();
        }
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.tiporientation">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Hi - you do not need to change the layouts manually.
Just in the layout preview of Android Studio (xml editor) select "Create landscape" version and let studio assign everything for you. This way the correct layout file is placed in the correct folder and you do not need any code at all to rotate.

Post the registration of your activity in the manifest - are there configuration entries? the method you posted is from the onConfigurationChanged callback?

Comment: My assignment wants us to make 2 separate XMLs and use an if/else if like I used above to switch between the two.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with 2 xml's --- android studio will do the same. It's the place WHERE they are stored and let android do what it can do best.
Still missing your manifest registration of the activity and your onConfigrationChanged method. can't help without that

Comment: updated I added my whole MainActivity and manifest !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the onConfigurationChanged callback your activity is destroyed and re-created.
Values in your text fields can be stored in the `savedInstanceState` and then retrieved in onCreate.

I am not entirely sure, but *I think* what happens here is:

- Phone rotates
- Phone recreates the activity (your onCreate runs)
- you receive the onConfiguration callback
- there you assign a new contentView(_landscape)
- and with this you destroy the layout just rendered in onCreate and your listeners

Your `onCreate` has already run, thus your `TextWatcher` was attached to a layout you just destroyed with your setContentView call from `modifyLayout`.

I still think you should let android manage this for you, but to solve the problem, I suggest:

- remove the code from onCreate beginning with the first findViewById up to (and including) the .addTextWatcher lines
- remove the other clutter with an additional modifyLayout call from your onCreate
- put this code in a method, say `connectWatchers`
- call this method from `onCreate`
- call this method from `modifyLayout`

It should look like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    tipCalc = new TipCalculator(.17f,100);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    connectWatchers();
}

private void modifyLayout(Configuration newConfig) {
    if(newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_landscape); //we create new XML for this layout
    else if(newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    connectWatchers();
}

public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    Log.w("MainActivity", "Inside onConfigurationChanged");
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    modifyLayout(newConfig); //if orientation changes again, send back to modifyLayout
}

private void connectWatchers() {
    billEditText = findViewById(R.id.EDIT_BillAmount);
    tipEditText = findViewById(R.id.EDIT_EnterTip);
    TextChangeHandler tch = new TextChangeHandler();
    billEditText.addTextChangedListener(tch);
    tipEditText.addTextChangedListener(tch);
}
```